# Android cordova phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am new to PhoneGap Android development. There is an issue when I try to run the application.
The application consists of whitelist-plugin as well.
Before I had run the application successfully, but now I get the following exception:

[image: Here is the screenshot of the exception]

I need help to solve the same.It would be great if someone help me out with this.

Comment: there is no link to the screenshot

Comment: post your main activity code.

Comment: Are you saying that you only started getting this problem after adding the white-list problem ? If so can you specify how you added the plugin ? It looks like the plugin cannot be loaded which might be due to incorrect versioning

Comment: @Fido : 
I wanted to add Cordova WebView in my application. 
I used the cordova install plugin command. While installing the plugin i didn't specify any version.

Comment: @jaydroider : 
Here is my MainActivity.java -- 


`package io.cordova.hellocordova;

import android.os.Bundle;

import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity

{

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml

        loadUrl(launchUrl);

    }

}`

Comment: r u getting above mentioned exception after installed any of the plugins ?

Comment: @jaydroider : Yes.
Now that I removed everything and started all with new, the application is running the way it was before.

Comment: that's great and when u install any of the plugins try to install using git url.

Comment: @jaydroider : sure!
But still couldn't understand the reason behind the exception!

Comment: u have installed plugin manually or with using commands ? might be a problem in link u have used for installation. or which plugin u have tried to install could u mention that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100119/discussion-between-neha-and-jaydroider).

Comment: @Neha Did you solve your issue? It appears you were getting some bad advice.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 : I had made some changes in the config.xml file. This was the reason why I was getting exception.

Comment: There is not enough information to solve this issue. Your question is poor. Your issue is not described well. I'm surprised no one tagged this issue. Would you like to rewrite your question? or study some videos? or something else?

Comment: @Neha Have you solved your issue?

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 Not really.